# ARIMA in Python & R

Tags: python, r, time-series

In `auto.arima` in `R`, we select `(p,d,q) & (P,D,Q)` respectively but in `auto_arima` in `Python` we select `(p,0,q) & (0,d,0)` respectively.

What is the difference between the two selections? Does `auto_arima` in `Python` take care of constant & drift as `auto.arima` in `R`? Could we choose a `SARIMAX Model` in `Python` using `auto_arima`?

If yes, then how? Besides, how could I set some coefficients to zero in `ARIMA` in `Python` as we do with fixed command in `ARIMA` in `R`?

Comment: Can you give an example of data and codes to verify your claim?